# Creating a trigger with SQLAlchemy DDL causes issue with "%s" in trigger

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm currently trying to learn the basics of `SQLAlchemy` after having relied upon `sqlite3` before. I'm attempting to create a table with triggers, but I've hit a problem with getting the current unix timestamp.

The code for generating the timestamp in sqlite is `strftime("%s", "now")`, but it causes an error as `%s` is parsed before it gets to the trigger insert.

By executing the event, it gets formatted to `strftime("{'table': u'"Users"', 'fullname': u'"Users"', 'schema': ''}", "now")`. Is there a way I can avoid this happening?

Alternatively, is it a better practice to just create the initial database with triggers in sqlite (bearing in mind I later plan to move to MySQL), and just use SQLAcademy for access to it all within my code?

Here's my current test code:

```
import sqlalchemy as db

engine = db.create_engine('sqlite://')
connection = engine.connect()
metadata = db.MetaData(engine)


if engine.dialect.has_table(engine, 'Users'):
    users = db.Table('Users', metadata, autoload=True)
else:
    users = db.Table(
        'Users', metadata,
        db.Column('row_id', db.Integer(), primary_key=True),
        db.Column('name', db.String(255), nullable=False),
        db.Column('num_logins', db.Integer(), default=0),
        db.Column('time_registered', db.Integer(), nullable=True),
        db.Column('time_updated', db.Integer(), nullable=True)
    )

    trigger = db.DDL("""
    CREATE TRIGGER user_update AFTER UPDATE ON Users
        FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
            UPDATE Users SET date_modified = strftime("%s", "now") WHERE row_id = NEW.row_id;
        END;
    """)
    db.event.listen(users, 'after_create', trigger.execute_if(dialect='sqlite'))
    users.create(engine)
```

I tried escaping the characters which just broke things, and passing in another '%s' as the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a very simple issue, I'll leave this up though in case anyone else comes across it.

When digging into the source code I found this line midway through `\sqlalchemy\sql\ddl.py`: `A literal '%' in a statement must be escaped as '%%'.`

Works fine when using `strftime("%%s", "now")`.

Comment: The reason is that SQLA makes certain things such as table and schema name available in DDL using named %-formatting, though if you have unescaped `%s` in the string, it causes a revert to positional %-formatting, and so the whole argument dict is formatted in. This is also in the docs: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/ddl.html#sqlalchemy.schema.DDL

Comment: Thanks, I'm reading more of the docs but there's just so much information. Currently having a look at relationships which I'm hoping can take the place of triggers if set up correctly.